# Word NewDocument event is not triggering when opening 2nd new word document from taskbar

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I am working on word application VSTO. In the start up of word I have subscribed to Application.DocumentOpen and Application.NewDocument

After the first instance of Word(Application.DocumentOpen event is triggered) is open , if I try to create new blank document by right click on the Word icon in the task bar and chooses new blank documment then a new Word document is created. However NewDocument event do not fire . I do see that Application.WindowActivate fires. Could any one please help on why NewDocument event is not triggering/ how to overcome this problem.

I also wanted to point out that opening an existing document by right clicking on the Word icon in the taskbar fires the Application.DocumentOpen event and creating a blank document from the file tab also fires the Application.NewDocument event.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the only event that is always working as expected is `Application.DocumentChange`.

It fires when any (new or already opened) document becomes active.

You can add a bit of your own logic if it is important for you whether the document was just opened or the user just switched to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The NewDocument is fired, but the add-in is not ready to handle it at this stage. That's why you can see only `DocumentChange` events.

Answer (score 0):

That is because two separate `word.exe` processes are started, so your add-in is not yet initialized when a new document is created. At startup of add-in you can check whether any document is created and mimic the event yourself.

I get the `NewDocument` event fired correctly after the add-in is initialized. For examepl, if you open a document programmatically and then try to create a new document in the same Word instance/process the `NewDocument` is fired correctly. But when you start a new process and the add-in is not yet fully initialized for this instance/process the event is skipped when a document is created. You need to detect such cases in the add-in and handle them as known issues when dealing with the Word object model.